# Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setDataValidation

Tags: string, google-apps-script, exception, multidimensional-array, parameters

I am making a very simple Code for Google App Script and when executing it I am getting the error mentioned in the title.
I use Google Sheets interchangeably in Spanish and English Language. I am wondering if this might generate a Configuration problem that I didn't figure out yet.
I have tried almost every form of possible Syntax regarding Arrays but none has worked.
Here is the CODE:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('work');
  var list = ["A","B","C"];

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build;
  
  ws.getRange("B2").setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the parenthesis on `build()`.

Replace

```
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build;
```

With

```
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();
```

Comment: Oh I see! I am sorry for such a newbie question but may I ask you how did you know that the Error was caused by the omission of the parenthesis on build?

Comment: I knew that `build()` is a method and needed `()`.  And that the parameter to `setDataValidation()` must be a rule.  So tracing it back `rule` was incorrect so where was `rule` defined and that's where I see the mistake.  Just experience.  Someday you'll get it too.